# How to generate object @Entities from database?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, code-generation

I want to generate JPA's `@Entity`s from database (but I want it to be object oriented). for Example

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "badges")
public class Badges implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private User user;
    private String name;
    private String date;
```

It would be cool if it also support ManyToOne, OneToMany, Parent and ManyToMany.

P.S. I tried JBoss Tools(Hibernate Tools) and I did not work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [JBoss Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) (formerly hibernate tools).

Quote from their site:

> Reverse Engineering: The most powerful feature of Hibernate Tools is a database reverse engineering tool that can generate domain model classes and Hibernate mapping files, **annotated EJB3 entity beans**, HTML documentation or even an entire JBoss Seam application in seconds!

Comment: I  tried, but I was not able to configure it :( and when I did it It just did not generate the files.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of the jboss tools and follow this tutorial: http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.GA/en/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html#refeng_codegen

Comment: I have 3.2.0, maybe It just doesnt support MySQL. However I dont see any pictures there that shows it generates object oriented @entities(I get it to generate @entities with fields like Integer userId).

Comment: @01: a) MySQL is supported if you supply the mysql driver jar b) see the exporter section http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.GA/en/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html#exportes : 'Generate EJB3 annotations' is what you want.