# Generate JPA2 Entities from Existing Database using Maven

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa

[Generate JPA 2 Entities from existing Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833329/generate-jpa-2-entities-from-existing-database)

I want to do same but using maven build.

Please suggest the plugin. As i googled it, i found the metamodel generation of JPA using JPA annotation entities.Didn't find anything related to this question.

Comment: I have just created a blog for this: http://ggl-consulting.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-create-maven-jpa-project-from.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SInce you are using hibernate the default option would be [hibernate3-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/hibernate3-maven-plugin/), more specifically the `hibernate3:hbm2java` goal configured with `<ejb3>true</ejb3>`. It will generate annotated pojos (most annotations are from the standard `javax.persistence` package, but it might also include custom `org.hibernate.annotations`) .

Check out [John Citizen's answer](https://community.jboss.org/message/801478#801478) at [JBoss Community](https://community.jboss.org) for sample configuration.

Comment: is there an eclipselink way of doing this? what does netbeans/eclipse do internally?

Comment: Kalpesh, actually you can use hibernate maven plugin as well (it will produce clean JPA Entities using those settings). I'm not sure if there is a specific maven tool for eclipselink (this is a good question). I'm also not sure of what Dali and Netbeans do internally.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [hibernate-tools-maven-plugin](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.hibernate%20AND%20a:hibernate-tools-maven-plugin). In order to use it you can use the following configuration:

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.200</h2.version>
    <hibernate-tools-maven-plugin.version>5.4.11.Final</hibernate-tools-maven-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-tools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-tools-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <!-- DB Driver of your choice -->
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>Display Help</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>help</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>Entity generation</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>hbm2java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <ejb3>true</ejb3>
              <jdk5>true</jdk5>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>Schema generation</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <delimiter>;</delimiter>
              <haltOnError>true</haltOnError>
              <format>true</format>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <revengFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/hibernate/hibernate.reveng.xml</revengFile>
          <configFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml</configFile>
          <detectManyToMany>true</detectManyToMany>
          <detectOneToOne>true</detectOneToOne>
          <detectOptimisticLock>true</detectOptimisticLock>
          <createCollectionForForeignKey>true</createCollectionForForeignKey>
          <createManyToOneForForeignKey>true</createManyToOneForForeignKey>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Run `mvn generate-resources` and you will find generated JPA Entities and a Schema DDL of the test.mv.db H2-Database (root folder from the project).

The connection configuration is in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file located in `src/main/hibernate`. In our case has the following content:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:./test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

We use the `hibernate.reveng.xml` file to customize the mapping type configuration, for example in order to use the `java.time` types we can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering SYSTEM
  "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>

  <type-mapping>
    <sql-type jdbc-type="DATE" hibernate-type="java.time.LocalDate"/>
    <sql-type jdbc-type="TIMESTAMP" hibernate-type="java.time.LocalDateTime"/>
  </type-mapping>

</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

The complete project is available over on [Github](https://github.com/earth001/hibernate-tools-maven-plugin-sample).

Answer (score 4):

The official one to achieve this is [hibernate-tools-maven-plugin](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools/tree/master/maven). Here is a blog with a detailed explanation on how to integrate the plugin.

https://web.archive.org/web/20201013105933/https://jonamlabs.com/how-to-use-hibernate-tools-maven-plugin-to-generate-jpa-entities-from-an-existing-database/

Answer (score 3):

You should try MinuteProject:(it generates maven projects)

http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/

http://javacodesamples.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/jpa2-reverse-engineering-tool/

Comment: Unfortunately wikispaces is no longer running.

Comment: did you know another tool like this ?

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to save your time, and generate without learn too much then follow [this github code](https://github.com/smartnews/jpa-entity-generator) and generate in 3 small steps
- just add plugin in your maven project,
- update db credentials in entityGenConfig.yml file
- and execute "mvn jpa-entity-generator:generateAll"
- That's it, it will generate entity classes in given package, you need to use text replace for remove extra things

Comment: You will get idea only by reading README.md file