# Can EclipseLink be used to reverse engineer a database?

Tags: eclipselink

In particular, can it be used programmatically, via an Ant task, or from the command line?

I need to include reverse engineering of our database to Java classes (POJOs / Entity classes) in our build script.

It seems that Netbeans uses EclipseLink to do reverse engineering through a wizard and the results are exactly what I want!  I just need to do it from the command line or within the Gradle build script.

Comment: Not that I've seen. I've used hibernate tools (aka hbm2java) to create entity classes, and they work with eclipselink.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Hibernate and it is working pretty well.  Though, it took a long time to get working because the initial tests I did generated no entities and gave no output, so I had no idea what was wrong.  I eventually learned that the hibernate pom didn't declare a dependency on a logger so logging was disabled by default!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833329/generate-jpa-2-entities-from-existing-database