# Configure the JPA provider for a dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

I wanted to configure the persistence provider for a dynamic web project which I made insided eclipse luna EE edition. I googled `eclipse add persistence provider` and found nice only one step by step [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.orm.doc/html/files/libAndFacetForJPA.html) for this. Unfortunately, it only tells me how to create a new JPA project and set the persistence provider. How do I do this for a dynamic web project which has already been created ? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your project > right click > properties > search for project facets > Follow the screenshot below for remaining steps. I assume that the EclipseLink or some persistence provider libraries were downloaded and added to the build path already. So you will see them in the screens below.

[image]

Comment: Earlier, eclipse would not show me option 2. I deleted and reimported the project and the option came up. I got lucky again. W00t !

Comment: @peeskillet - yes. thanks. I looked at your post again and did all the stuff so that some unlucky guy does not get stuck like me.