# Generate JPA Entities from existing Database Tables

Tags: jpa, ejb, entity, openjpa

How can I generate JPA entities beans from database tablas?
I am using OpenJPA but has so much bugs and apparently the project is stopped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate JPA 2 Entities from existing Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833329/generate-jpa-2-entities-from-existing-database)

Answer (score 0):

With Netbeans - its built in.

Right click project -> New -> Generate entity classes from database.