# Can I wire hibernate to existing database tables?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

At the moment we're using ***python*** with ***django***. We're splitting our monolithic api into a bunch of micro-services. For the moment we will be using our current database built with ***Django***, and then gradually splitting the micro-services up into their own databases.

I'm wanting to use the ***java*** configuration without having to use ***xml***.

How would I go about wiring ***hibernate*** up to an existing db table? Are there any tutorials or is it as simple as creating the ***jpa*** models and adding a config to point them to existing tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it as simple as creating the jpa models and adding a config to point them to existing tables

Just be sure to let hbm2ddl.auto configured to validate, see: [Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do), guessing your db user has alter table grant.

Btw, you may want to use reverse engineering as well, check: [Generate JPA 2 Entities from existing Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833329/generate-jpa-2-entities-from-existing-database)

Comment: Great! I thought there may have been more to it.